# Upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and system time is very off

Tags: 16.04, time

Was dual booting 14.04 with no issues and decided to upgrade to 16.04 yesterday. The system clock was very off.

Searching around I added `UTC=no` to `/etc/default/rcS` to no avail. I manually adjusted the clock for now but need it to be synchronized to the world UTC :)

Running `ntpdate` fails:

```
$ ntpdate -q ntp.ubuntu.com
server 91.189.94.4, stratum 0, offset 0.000000, delay 0.00000
server 91.189.89.199, stratum 0, offset 0.000000, delay 0.00000
server 91.189.89.198, stratum 0, offset 0.000000, delay 0.00000
server 91.189.91.157, stratum 0, offset 0.000000, delay 0.00000
 5 Aug 08:31:09 ntpdate[10462]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

Running `timedatectl`:

```
$ timedatectl
      Local time: Fri 2016-08-05 08:36:58 SGT
  Universal time: Fri 2016-08-05 00:36:58 UTC
        RTC time: Fri 2016-08-05 08:36:58
       Time zone: Asia/Singapore (SGT, +0800)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: yes

Warning: The system is configured to read the RTC time in the local time zone.
         This mode can not be fully supported. It will create various problems
         with time zone changes and daylight saving time adjustments. The RTC
         time is never updated, it relies on external facilities to maintain it.
         If at all possible, use RTC in UTC by calling
         'timedatectl set-local-rtc 0'.
```

it says NTP synchronized and network time on but checking with websites like [time.is](http://time.is/UTC) shows that my clock is off by around 40 seconds

Answer (score 1):

go ahead and set time manually, being certain that correct time zone is chosen. Once done and satisfied, shut off PC (off, not restart). Now, turn PC back on. If time and date are shown to be Jan 1, 2001 you need to replace the CMOS battery. This can be found on the motherboard, large 'watch' battery - CR2032. be careful when removing for the receiving pocket
can be damaged rather easily. 
                                 Hope this helps, Craig

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem with every upgrade. My solution was to go in manually and update the timezone, date format and time. This has worked for me.

Comment: Manual update works but for time sensitive operations depending on system time it's not the best solution imo